# mysql database replication error log. Ways to retrieve it

Tags: mysql, replication

Does mysql logs replication errors? I tried to google around but not much help.
If the errors are logged, where is it logged?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are running on a Linux environment, the short answer is that it is liking in the `mysql.err` file in your `logs` directory.

A more detailed answer can be found by executing this command

```
lsof -nc mysqld | grep -vE '(\.so(\..*)?$|\.frm|\.MY?|\.ibd|ib_logfile|ibdata|TCP)'
```

This will list all files that your database has open. From here you are looking for these two lines:

```
COMMAND   PID  USER   FD   TYPE      DEVICE  SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
mysqld  30257 mysql    1w   REG       253,4     10229   270851 /var/log/mysql/mysql.err
mysqld  30257 mysql    2w   REG       253,4     10229   270851 /var/log/mysql/mysql.err
```

This is showing that, MySQL writes log messages and errors into `/var/log/mysql/mysql.err`. `1w` and `2w` are file descriptors 1 (`stdout`) and 2 (`stderr`) and both were redirected from console to the specified file.

More information about the files that appear in that command can be found in this [article](http://www.dbasquare.com/2012/06/02/how-to-find-mysql-binary-logs-error-logs-temporary-files/).